# Multiple subscribers to the OnSendingHeaders event in an owin middleware

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin

I have two middlewares similar to the ones below which are both subscribing to the `OnSendingHeaders` event. One sets some headers and the other one removes some headers:

```
public class Middleware1 : OwinMiddleware
{
    public Middleware1(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        context.Response.OnSendingHeaders(state =>
        {
            var res = (OwinResponse)state;

            // im removing some headers

        }, context.Response);

        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}

public class Middleware2 : OwinMiddleware
{
    public Middleware2(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        context.Response.OnSendingHeaders(state =>
        {
            var res = (OwinResponse)state;

            // im setting some headers

        }, context.Response);

        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

I also have web api controllers that creates excel and pdf-documents and returns an `IHttpActionResult`. That piece of code is working as intended.

However, when I issue a request to a controller that returns a pdf/excel-document, the response gets aborted in my browser after the headers are sent. The response is sent back as a http status code `200` and the correct `Content-Length` header is sent, but the file to be downloaded gets aborted.

This error seems to be tied to the subscribing of the `OnSendingHeaders` event. Because if I remove the middlewares or set/remove the headers without subscribing to the event (calling `context.Response.Headers` directly), everything works fine.

Is this event not supposed to be subscribed to multiple times or what could otherwise be causing this issue?

Comment: Having multiple subscribers should be fine. Is this on IIS? There were some issues with OnSendingHeaders not firing at the right time, causing some issues when you tried to modify the response.

Comment: Yes this was on IIS. The issue could be related to our load balancer since going directly to the servers did not cause this behaviour.